# Path.Combine doesn`t work properly

Tags: c#, path

I have

```
string path = "path";
string newPath = Path.Combine(path, "/jhjh/klk");
```

I expect that the result will be `newPth = path/"/jhjh/klk"`

But get `"/jhjh/klk"` instead.

What is wrong with the method invocation?

Comment: "/jhjh" means "go to the root and then into jhjh. Remove the leading slash.

Comment: Start from the assumption that `Path.Combine` works correctly, and that you don't yet understand what it does. That will be more productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine will add the slash for you, so just do

```
string newPath = Path.Combine("path", @"jhjh\klk");
```

Comment: Whats with the extra Data class? You will only need the last sentence?

Comment: @RvdK the OP modified the original question where that was present, I just replied to the question

Answer (score 3):

From [`Path.Combine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> The combined paths. If one of the specified paths is a zero-length
>   string, this method returns the other path. **If path2 contains an
>   absolute path, this method returns path2**.

`Path.Combine` method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,2d7263f86a526264) as;

```
public static String Combine(String path1, String path2) {
        if (path1==null || path2==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException((path1==null) ? "path1" : "path2");
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        CheckInvalidPathChars(path1);
        CheckInvalidPathChars(path2);

        return CombineNoChecks(path1, path2);
}
```

Here how `CombineNoChecks` method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,16ed6da326ce4745);

```
private static String CombineNoChecks(String path1, String path2) {
        if (path2.Length == 0)
            return path1;

        if (path1.Length == 0)
            return path2;

        if (IsPathRooted(path2))
            return path2;

        char ch = path1[path1.Length - 1];
        if (ch != DirectorySeparatorChar && ch != AltDirectorySeparatorChar && ch != VolumeSeparatorChar) 
            return path1 + DirectorySeparatorChar + path2;
        return path1 + path2;
    }
```

And `IsPathRooted` method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,807960f08fca497d);

```
public static bool IsPathRooted(String path) {
if (path != null) {

    int length = path.Length;
    if ((length >= 1 && (path[0] == DirectorySeparatorChar || path[0] == AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
#if !PLATFORM_UNIX                       
         || (length >= 2 && path[1] == VolumeSeparatorChar)
#endif
         ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your case (`path2` is `/jhjh/klk`) That makes your `path[0]` is `/`. That's why your `path[0] == DirectorySeparatorChar` and `length >= 1` expressions returns `true` and that's why your `IsPathRooted` method returns `true` and that's why your `CombineNoChecks` method returns `path2`.

Comment: Out of interest here, why show the implementations? It is perfectly possible to analyse this by reading the documentation and I personally think that it is better to encourage novices to do that. As written this seems to suggest to a novice that the way to learn how to use methods like `Path.Combine` is to obtain the source code and read it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think showing the source code as well would be better to read and understand how and what absolute path and relative path exactly are. Reading documentations is fine as well, but digging the source code is always a plus. Of course this is just the matter of taste.

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree here. I am completely at odds with you on this one. :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am glad to disagree with you sir only if we both provide the same solution `:)`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

> If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2.

This is your scenario. You pass an absolute path as the second parameter, and so that absolute path is returned.

Perhaps your mistake is that you are passing an absolute path as the second parameter but intended to pass a relative path. The fact that `"/jhjh/klk"` begins with a path separator is what makes it be an absolute path.